# Astronomical objects that should have magnetic bubbles similar to those found by the Voyager probe at the edge of our solar system

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, astrophysics, astronomy, stars

I've known about the existence of magnetic bubbles at Solar System's edge from a video edited by NASA from an official channel of YouTube, I refer [1] (as explicitly stated in the title, it was a probe that discovered it). On the other hand I know from an informative point of view that stars are classified according different ways, in short that our Sun is just a kind of star with stellar mass a solar mass ($M_{\odot}$). Wikipedia has an article for [*Astronomical object*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_object) that shows a classification of astronomical objects, in particular for example a binary star that is a compound object, or for example different giant stars or different as compact stars (see if you want the Wikipedia [*Compact star*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_star) as example of which a non-professional or the general public can understand as *a star*: I mean my understanding of such astronomical objects).

> **Question.** I'm curious about if it possible to say something about the existence of similar magnetic bubbles for *stars* different than our solar system. Is it possible to narrow or discard the list of stars that will have those similar magnetic bubbles that our own solar system has? **Many thanks.**

I don't know if there is literature about it, I'm asking if you can to provide a helpful/concise answer at least for some astronomical objects (the more relevant stars for which you consider that our question is answerable).

I hope that it is possible say something about it (I evoke what work can be done to elucidate something about my question). I'm asking it as a curiosity, I am not a physicist. One can to read my previous question as these: Is it obvious that stars of a different class than our Sun will have these same structures (explained in the slide at minute $\approx 1:36$ from [1])? What work can be done about it?

### References:

[1] *NASA |Voyager Finds Magnetic Bubbles at Solar System's Edge*, from the official channel **NASA Goddard** of YouTube (June, 9th 2011).

Comment: I hope that my question does make sense, feel free to edit if you can to improve some aspect of the post. The title of my post refers astronomical objects, stars as I refer (from binary star to compact stars: *a star*) having magnetic bubbles of a similar nature to those found by the Voyager probe at the edge of our solar system, those explained in the reference [1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I could understand, these bubbles form because the star has this wavy, spiral shaped magnetic field. As most of the stars (binary or not) has similar magnetic fields, probably they also have these bubbles. I'm not sure how dose the magnetic field look like in case of a white dwarf or a neutron star, but maybe even those have these bubbles. (Although a neutron star usually has more 'exotic' magnetic field. Also I think a black hole doesn't have these bubbles, as its magnetic field is different, as far as I know.) The lack of literature is because we couldn't observe these structures around other stars. [This](http://www.solarsystemcentral.com/heliosphere_page.html) article might worth to read. Also the heliosphere like structures around other stars are called **astrospheres** or **stellar-wind bubbles**.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and reference that I've added to my notebook to study these. I wondered about a helpful and concise answer and I think that yours fits with my post.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help. Although this question might better fits the _Astronomy_ site. Anyway, if I could answer your question, please accept (and not just upvote) my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I am not a physicist and I think that the right thing (in my view since I've asked the question yesterday) is wait some days if some user wants to add more feedback or answers, before I'm accepting an answer. Thanks you very much again.

Comment: The results from the Voyager observations imply such magnetic 'bubbles' are an effect of the spiral-shaped magnetic field of the Sun. Since the Sun's magnetic field has a spiral shape because the Sun is rotating, albeit rotating slowly, we should expect that all stars will have these 'bubbles', given that all stars rotate. For stars which rotate rapidly, such as neutron stars, which rotate once a second, the bubbles may be very different in character from those produced by a normal star, which rotates only once in many hours. But we ought to expect all rotating magnetic fields to produce them.